# Why i have extra characters when copying a part of an unsigned char array in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, unsigned-char

I am trying to divide an unsigned char array and place it in 3 variables.
The original variable: **0000000300000008544368616d696568**

The output should be :

```
tag= **00000003**
length = **00000005**
value = **544368616d696568**
```

To get the tag & length:

```
- (BOOL)decodeTag:(unsigned char*) data{

    unsigned char *byteTag;
    byteTag = [self CopyArray:byteTag :0 :data :0 :4*2];

    NSString *s=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)byteTag];
    NSString *dataAsString = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    unsigned intData = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:dataAsString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&intData];

    int tag = intData;
    self.tag = tag;
    NSLog(@"decode tag %i", tag);
    return true;
 }
```

To get the value:

```
- (BOOL)decodeValue:(unsigned char*) data{

    unsigned char* value=(unsigned char *)calloc(self.length*2, sizeof(unsigned char));
    value= [self CopyArrays:value :0 :data :8*2 : self.length *2];
    self.value = value;
    NSLog(@"data %s",data);
    NSLog(@"value %s",value);
    return true;
  }
```

To copy a part of the unsigned char array:

```
- (unsigned char*)CopyArrays:(unsigned char *) destination :(int) destIndex :(unsigned char *) source :(int) sourceIndexStart  :(int) length{
for ( int i=0; i<length; i++){
    destination[i+destIndex] = source[i+sourceIndexStart];
}
return destination;
}
```

But as a result for the value variable, i get the following:
**544368616d696568\255\276\232zY\300ݺ**

Comment: You forget to *terminate the strings*?

Comment: how to do it please?

Comment: At `byteTag = [self CopyArray:byteTag :0 :data :0 :4*2];` I stopped reading the Q. Please get an introduction to Objective-C.

Comment: Copy the strings with `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data + 4*2 length:4*2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.